# INDEX MATCH array formula error for table with single row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working with INDEX MATCH formula with multiple criteria in a Excel Table. My array formula looks like

```
{=INDEX(Table1[Column3],MATCH(1,(Table1[Column1]=value1)*(Table1[Column2]=value2), 0))}
```

The formula works fine if table has more than one row. The formula fails and returns #N/A when table has 1 row. Is there any workaround for table with single row?

My Table is pulling data through database using power query. Hence number of rows are dynamic. Table is as follows

```
Column1  |  Column2  |  Column3
-------------------------------
value1   |  value2   |  value3
```

Comment: Can't replicate, works fine for me. What column are your trying to return? Column3? Then try: `=INDEX(Table1[Column3],MATCH(1,INDEX((Table1[Column1]="Value1")*(Table1[Column2]="Value2"),),0))`

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was searching for. `INDEX` inside `MATCH` is what was required. Please add this comment as answer so that it can be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, I couldn't replicate but I would recommend using:

```
=INDEX(Table1[Column3],MATCH(1,INDEX((Table1[Column1]="Value1")*(Table1[Column2]="Value2"),),0))
```

Index inside Match is not required but mimics the CSE behaviour. Without the index inside, you'll need to enter it as Array.