# Excel Match function: Lookup of multiple values in multiple lookup arrays not working when there is just one row in the lookup array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to lookup three lookup values in cells `A8`, `B8` and `C8` in table columns `Number1`, `Number2` and `String1`. This is the formula I am using:

```
=MATCH(A8&B8&C8,tbl[Number1]&tbl[Number2]&tbl[String1],0)
```

It works fine, when I have multiple rows in the lookup array. But I get a `#VALUE!` error when there is just one row.

**Not working:**

[image: Not working example of a match formula on multiple columns with just one row]

**Working:**

[image: Working example of a match formula on multiple columns with multiple lookup rows]

It looks fine when I evaluate the formula, but Excel does not seem to recognize the second "12a" as an array:

[image: Evaluate formula]

Can this problem be avoided and the formula improved?

Comment: It's a sidenote, but I'd steer clear from looking for concatenated values. What if a2 = 1 and b2 = 11 and you are looking for '111'? There will be plenty of cases of people that yield false positives without realizing. On-topic, you can use `INDEX()` to make this work: `=MATCH(1,INDEX((tbl[Number1]=A8)*(tbl[Number2]=B8)*(tbl[String1]=C8),),0)` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59965280/9758194) possible duplicate.

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: @JvdV Thank you so much for your comment.  Actually, the original formula that I use is: `=MATCH(A7&"-"&B7&"-"&C7;tbl[Number1]&"-"&tbl[Number2]&"-"&tbl[String1];0)`, but I wanted to keep the problem as simple as possible for those answering me :-).

Comment: @JvdV And by the way, your solution works perfeclty. Thank you!

Comment: @JvdV Sorry, my mistake. It is fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to coerce the return to an array:

`=MATCH(A8&B8&C8,IF({1},tbl[Number1]&tbl[Number2]&tbl[String1]),0)`